# Checking for quick actions availability

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, 3dtouch

I'm using home screen quick actions that's only supported in `IOS9`. 
Using the constant `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey` will crash if used in `IOS8`. 
What is the correct way to check if quick actions is supported?

One way is to check for `IOS9` through systemVersion but I'm hoping there is a better way. 

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In objective C you can check to see if a class exists. Say something like

```
if([UIApplicationShortcutItem class]){
//Handle shortcut launch
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in case of `Swift` the best way for checking the `API` availability is `Automatic operating system API availability checking` that's new feature released with `iOS9` and `Swift2`

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    // use UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey
} else {
    // no available
}
```

`#available` is going to check whether are we using iOS 9 or later, or any other unknown platforms like `watchOS` so the `*` is also here.

If your code is inside a function then you can use `#available` with `guard` like this.

```
guard #available(iOS 9, *) else {
    return
}
```

Mark your methods and class as well like

```
@available(iOS 9, *)
func useMyStackView() {
    // use UIStackView
}
```

`@available` works similarly to `#available` so If your deployment target is `iOS7` or less than 9, you can't call that `useMyStackView()`

Comment: 1+ for a really great answer to swift

Answer (score 0):

For Objc, it also can use `@available (iOS 9, *)` to check the OS version

```
if (@available(iOS 9, *)) {
    //use UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey
}
```